# Reference to vector of parent or child

Tags: c++, inheritance, stdvector

I have recently created a class inheriting from another preexisiting one

```
class Child: public Parent{
    ...
};
```

and another class that contains a reference to a vector of parents

```
// foo.h
class Foo{
private:
    std::vector<Parent>& things;
public:
    Foo(std::vector<Parent>& things);
    // + a bunch of other member functions
};
```

The members are implemented in a separate file

```
// foo.cpp
Foo::Foo(std::vector<parent>& things):things(things){}
// ... other member functions of Foo
```

I want to make `Foo` work with vectors of type`std::vector<Child>` as well.

I am aware I could make Foo a template

```
template<class c>
class Foo{
...
```

and add the following lines to the end of foo.cpp to avoid linker errors

```
template class Foo<Parent>;
template class Foo<Child>;
```

This is not ideal because in the future `Child` likely not going to remain the only class inheriting from `Parent` and touching Foo.cpp every time a child of `Parent` is born seems not like an elegant solution to me.
Is there a better way, than making `Foo` a template?

Comment: Use *pointers* to the base (`Parent`) class? Then you can add pointers to any child class as well. Works very well with polymorphism.

Comment: Implement the template [in the header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Comment: Does Foo's vector own the Parent things?  Then for polymorphism, it should be `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Parent>> things;`  If it does **not** own the Parent objects in the things, then for polymorphism it should be `std::vector<Parent*> things;`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  and Eljay are right, pointers would be a smart solution, but would mean I need to touch all the code accessing elements of things. I will probably go with 1201ProgramAlarm's suggestion of moving the implementation to the header, since there are significantly less occurrences of Foo that I'd need to change.

Comment: If you want to allow mixed vectors (parents and children or different children together), you need a vector of pointers. If you want to disallow them, you probably need a template (but then you might ask yourself if inheritance is really appropriate here).

Comment: Ehmm, ok, but polymorphism works also with references, you know?